# Перекрытие зафиксированного элемента видео с YouTube

Tags: css

Как сделать, чтобы видео с youtube, rutube и прочих каналов не перекрывало зафиксированную строку или элемент посредством таких правил?

```
.cssdiv{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Comment: Хоть бы описали каким методом пытаетесь вставить ролик? CCS тут ничего не решает!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужен

```
wmode="opaque"
```

,если вставляете как флеш объект. Если html5 - все и так будет нормально

Comment: не помогает

Comment: это свойство для видео

Comment: @MaximPro вот как дожно помочь!

    <object //тратата>
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <embed //тут ваш набор атрибутов и добавить -> wmode="opaque"></embed>
    </object>